# MySQL LIMIT not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL 5.0 server, and I'm running this query:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM deals
    WHERE expires > "2012-05-25 19:37:58"
    AND city =2
    ORDER BY UIN
    LIMIT 48 , 57
```

And it's returning:

> Showing rows 0 - 29 (57 total, Query took 0.0036 sec)

Am I doing something wrong? I expect 9 rows, 48-57..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The second parameter to `LIMIT` is not an offset, it's a length relative to the offset. So if you want 9 rows, it would be `LIMIT 48, 9`.

Answer (score 4):

```
LIMIT 48 , 57
```

will show 57 records following the 48th record.

Try

```
LIMIT 48 , 9
```

http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm

Answer (score 1):

`LIMIT` work like this: `LIMIT (page - 1) * post_per_page, post_per_page`